# Can't install Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 in KVM with minimal disk size

Tags: server, partitioning, system-installation, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server 18.04.3 in KVM with minimal resources. When I checked the official [Ubuntu System Requirements](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/installation), it says for live server (which I am using) it needs 1.5 gigabyte and for Standard it needs 2.5 gigabytes.

When I tried to create a VM instance with *5 gigabytes* disk the installer wouldn't let me select the disk. I tried increasing the disk to *5.5 gigabytes* and got the same result. Only after I increased the disk size to *6 gigabytes* the installer would allow me to select the disk for installation. 6 gigabytes is **more than double** of the documented minimal disk size.

Can anyone please explain this?

Screenshots:

1. Trying with 5 gigabytes disk:

[image: Trying with 5 gigabytes disk]

2. Trying with 5.5 gigabytes disk:

[image: Trying with 5.5 gigabytes disk]

3. Trying with 6 gigabytes disk

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need space for the swap file, the documented space requirements are strictly for the Operating System so yes, you need more than what it is telling you as a minimum.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! So it is just minimal size of OS files not a minimal system, right? If that is so it should be more clear in the documentations.